# Get remote certificate and interact with ESMTP server after STARTTLS

Tags: python, openssl, smtp, subprocess, starttls

I'm trying to interact with a remote ESMTP server from Python. I need to capture the client certificate and to issues commands after the STARTTLS command is sent. This is easily done with the OpenSSL command line tool, and I can do it easily from the command line. However when I do it from Python using subprocess, it fails.

Here is doing it from the command line:

```
[ec2-user@ec2 dane2]$ openssl s_client -starttls smtp -host aspmx.l.google.com -port 25 
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Inc, CN = Google Internet Authority G2
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google Inc, CN = mx.google.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=mx.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=mx.google.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: ECDH, prime256v1, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4491 bytes and written 408 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: F06DFB02F54C5D50F5077CDEE8878948BA288386D5BD51E78F4EB546FD56A277
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 3E53A3737CBD3C947F10BCE048B922996DA7E90EFC478AA780DC20CD9521FED7A56E0686ACC772215C9B6019119595BE
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 100800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - ea 82 db c4 9e 33 6d 42-d1 1e bc 1c 3d a0 a6 4b   .....3mB....=..K
    0010 - bb 6e 1c 1a a8 03 bb 71-90 2f bd 91 3d 90 9e a6   .n.....q./..=...
    0020 - d5 40 93 03 8d a7 34 6e-f5 bd 4e 10 42 7b 2a 5a   .@....4n..N.B{*Z
    0030 - e9 be 6a 85 4e e5 6d 34-62 74 43 47 0a 81 82 c7   ..j.N.m4btCG....
    0040 - 15 8b 1e fb 0f 2c 4f 51-2b a0 57 ad a7 90 4c 56   .....,OQ+.W...LV
    0050 - 3c a8 53 f3 9d 3f 39 03-52 4b e3 11 5a ce 46 19   <.S..?9.RK..Z.F.
    0060 - a2 2a 82 d2 72 aa 85 9c-31 06 fa fb 9c 07 9e 62   .*..r...1......b
    0070 - 35 a5 0a 60 a5 33 5f 24-2a 05 bd bb 6d 5d 2f 4d   5..`.3_$*...m]/M
    0080 - 23 66 d0 6e 5c fc 2c ce-84 a5 61 7e b6 e4 53 6d   #f.n\.,...a~..Sm
    0090 - 42 36 96 1a 5e f5 71 c8-52 dc 11 8b 9c a8 29 58   B6..^.q.R.....)X
    00a0 - be 56 3b 09                                       .V;.

    Start Time: 1436368455
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
250 SMTPUTF8
EHLO THERE
250-mx.google.com at your service, [52.7.167.73]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
QUIT
DONE
```

Here is a python program that should do it:

```
openssl_exe = 'openssl' 
import subprocess,os,sys

cmd = [openssl_exe,'s_client','-starttls','smtp','-host','aspmx.l.google.com','-port','25']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
w = p.communicate(b"EHLO THERE\r\n")
print("STDOUT={}".format(w[0]))
```

But here is the python program's results:

```
$ python stest.py
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
250 SMTPUTF8
DONE
STDOUT=CONNECTED(00000005)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=mx.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGhDCCBWygAwIBAgIIWBl3p3vZ2gQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwSTELMAkGA1UE
BhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAoTCkdvb2dsZSBJbmMxJTAjBgNVBAMTHEdvb2dsZSBJbnRl
cm5ldCBBdXRob3JpdHkgRzIwHhcNMTUwMjE4MTAxNDE1WhcNMTUxMjMxMDAwMDAw
WjBnMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECAwKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBwwN
TW91bnRhaW4gVmlldzETMBEGA1UECgwKR29vZ2xlIEluYzEWMBQGA1UEAwwNbXgu
Z29vZ2xlLmNvbTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAMv7SO16
/zsSbvvLqhtjFfg4D3D316mnl7kiPeyJZmPGJSUOc9Dat7mlvzEmREgVteM7rUJ+
dujErZR2BgqjE0Exet2q57F047ta8+jjIiZYmMpGoiyr8ArICutDSh/jkg43Sxvc
VvKyF93prWBAqWk9DlBdtYzmCGqa6afsV9Ar5C86wyyjjPihIXzAqXGO0qixMckT
x58xPVw5EcaK0OBnD/CD9U+y5FQAjTxSZCmA8BA+3O29I4yQYGHkwYWzZ/QGWx0U
jVGuoDn64ZVl8arpWVqQk+vlx3DT3+w73wazCIV4nVMW415OhoYUupS9F1hwt5Xl
fwi5rcWpSjIvRdMCAwEAAaOCA1AwggNMMB0GA1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMBBggr
BgEFBQcDAjCCAiYGA1UdEQSCAh0wggIZghJhc3BteC5sLmdvb2dsZS5jb22CF2Fs
dDEuYXNwbXgubC5nb29nbGUuY29tghdhbHQyLmFzcG14LmwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbYIX
YWx0My5hc3BteC5sLmdvb2dsZS5jb22CF2FsdDQuYXNwbXgubC5nb29nbGUuY29t
ghpnbWFpbC1zbXRwLWluLmwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbYIfYWx0MS5nbWFpbC1zbXRwLWlu
LmwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbYIfYWx0Mi5nbWFpbC1zbXRwLWluLmwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbYIf
YWx0My5nbWFpbC1zbXRwLWluLmwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbYIfYWx0NC5nbWFpbC1zbXRw
LWluLmwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbYIYZ21yLXNtdHAtaW4ubC5nb29nbGUuY29tgh1hbHQx
Lmdtci1zbXRwLWluLmwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbYIdYWx0Mi5nbXItc210cC1pbi5sLmdv
b2dsZS5jb22CHWFsdDMuZ21yLXNtdHAtaW4ubC5nb29nbGUuY29tgh1hbHQ0Lmdt
ci1zbXRwLWluLmwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbYINbXguZ29vZ2xlLmNvbYIVYXNwbXgyLmdv
b2dsZW1haWwuY29tghVhc3BteDMuZ29vZ2xlbWFpbC5jb22CFWFzcG14NC5nb29n
bGVtYWlsLmNvbYIVYXNwbXg1Lmdvb2dsZW1haWwuY29tMGgGCCsGAQUFBwEBBFww
WjArBggrBgEFBQcwAoYfaHR0cDovL3BraS5nb29nbGUuY29tL0dJQUcyLmNydDAr
BggrBgEFBQcwAYYfaHR0cDovL2NsaWVudHMxLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vb2NzcDAdBgNV
HQ4EFgQU+dGlczrTqRIeX+KOJZGoZuvSbH4wDAYDVR0TAQH/BAIwADAfBgNVHSME
GDAWgBRK3QYWG7z2aLV29YG2u2IaulqBLzAXBgNVHSAEEDAOMAwGCisGAQQB1nkC
BQEwMAYDVR0fBCkwJzAloCOgIYYfaHR0cDovL3BraS5nb29nbGUuY29tL0dJQUcy
LmNybDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEATvYWP0PucWPe09a4R1AiCI4hgskaUpXN
MZYWuD42qj5Ogp/ViajPlVjFowPeMoWfKzi2k3+4+aFCcsHHXMEe2umrTLyzonwF
X6jmzHj+5NGXuRRlGmPnHzzVWjEVbMhBwTQMneVkKVEL1HuAJlCoFr0uK2FtpYvt
CBfDr39PppsYS7Y3sB8ji3+bHhB3FMGXZLViJqVVPODMlDF6G7vRold08GHO9Led
nNSDImoOPhqj+pCJRv31GiDvI7PrlQQq5RRWGiFs09flqOKRnpyeMgqVicho/R3+
mjGh7k4tiUobGAvzYExi9gLydQIlNIf7SSxRPQ0rix9NIYMMa1jMXA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=mx.google.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4493 bytes and written 478 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: E4CA9A02C02D18C3078ECA0265855F7D7791D0B369305E12CC9DD4811020016C
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: CF0092DADDECFE4CE1FFDB581624DB7CB88E9BF7815EDEBAD39D43E94AEE47C681590981825B9A734006351D92984432
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 100800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - ea 82 db c4 9e 33 6d 42-d1 1e bc 1c 3d a0 a6 4b   .....3mB....=..K
    0010 - 65 ce b1 40 f3 99 bc 54-9e 97 8c 63 40 dc d2 6b   e..@...T...c@..k
    0020 - 8f 1e 8f 7f c2 7f 4a 57-e3 f1 4f cb 6b 65 ed 87   ......JW..O.ke..
    0030 - 8d fb ea a3 40 46 f2 05-82 ea 96 6e 5e de 48 56   ....@F.....n^.HV
    0040 - b9 24 f5 39 e5 11 1c bc-7b 7f e5 c8 d6 d8 a8 1e   .$.9....{.......
    0050 - 81 59 8c 52 24 43 39 b5-ff f4 d8 f8 1d b6 52 02   .Y.R$C9.......R.
    0060 - ab 24 11 76 18 1e ba c5-8c 49 7e 57 29 8f 91 d4   .$.v.....I~W)...
    0070 - 5d ab 5b 1e d4 bc 0f 08-ba 89 c8 d1 4c dc 6a 3a   ].[.........L.j:
    0080 - 38 6d 5e 89 ba 53 67 54-53 64 82 a9 79 93 f0 69   8m^..SgTSd..y..i
    0090 - 05 40 79 33 84 54 25 50-34 d2 af c7 99 3a a8 63   .@y3.T%P4....:.c
    00a0 - 13 95 46 02                                       ..F.

    Start Time: 1436368538
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
```

Why am I not getting the output of the `EHLO THERE` command?

Comment: You might need to set `shell=True`. Also there is the `ssl` as an alternative to using the client via `subprocess`.